# deleteArrayElements(number = 6, startIndex = 0, everyIth =2) should delete every second element out of the first 6 elements of the passed array

Tags: javascript, slice, splice

Implement the function deleteArrayElements() that reads N elements from the array starting from the given start index i and deletes every x-th element within this sub-array. The parameter startIndex can be greater than the length of the array. Implement a continuous addressing by looping through the array from the beginning again. The parameter everyIth can also be greater than the length of the array. However, at least one element, namely the 0-th element of the sub-array, should always be deleted. Return both the array without the deleted elements and the deleted elements

```
function deleteArrayElements(number, startIndex, everyIth) {
  let array = [];  
  let result = [];
  let removedItems = [];


  if (startIndex > array.length) {
    startIndex = startIndex % array.length;
  }

  for (let i = startIndex; i < startIndex + number; i += everyIth) {
    let indexToRemove = i % array.length;
    removedItems.push(array[indexToRemove]);
    array.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
  }

  result = array;
  return { newResult: result, removedItems: removedItems };
}
```

the expected output is
{"newResult":[null, "katze", null, "elefant", null, "stachelschwein", "affe", "giraffe"], "removedItems":["hund", "maus", "schlange"]};
but the output I get is:
{"newResult":["hund", "katze", "maus", "elefant", "schlange", "stachelschwein", "affe", "giraffe"], "removedItems":["hund", "elefant", "affe"]}

Comment: you need to loop from the end, because `splice` changes the position of the following indices.

Comment: so you mean for (let i = array.length; i >= startIndex + number; i -= everyIth)  ?

Comment: I tried that, but then the output arrays are empty

Comment: do you have the original data?

Comment: you could ask your teacher what they mean by "deleting element from an array". For example, what exactly should "delete even elements from [0,1,2,3]" do?

Comment: It should return the original array with the even elements replaced by 0 and then also return the “removed items” array which is filled with even elements so in the end it should return newresult=[0,1,null,3], removeditems=[2] @gog4

Answer (score 0):

Using splice won't add `null` in place of the element that was removed.  Since the length of the newResult should be the same as the length of array, using Array.map is a decent plan:

```js
let array = ["hund", "katze", "maus", "elefant", "schlange", "stachelschwein", "affe", "giraffe"];

function deleteArrayElements(number, startIndex, everyIth) {
  let removedItems = [];
  let result = array.map((el, i) => {
    if (i >= startIndex && i < startIndex + number && (i - startIndex) % everyIth === 0) {
      removedItems.push(el);
      return null;
    } else {
      return el;
    }
  });

  return { newResult: result, removedItems: removedItems };
}

console.log(deleteArrayElements(6, 0, 2));
console.log(deleteArrayElements(5, 7, 13));
```

Comment: thanks it worked perfectly for the first case now. Not for this one : 
expected :{"newResult":["hund", "katze", "maus", "elefant", "schlange", "stachelschwein", "affe", null], "removedItems":["giraffe"]}
output: {"newResult":["hund", "katze", "maus", "elefant", "schlange", "stachelschwein", "affe", "giraffe"], "removedItems":[]} meaning deleteArrayElements(5, 7, 13)

Comment: And also not for deleteArrayElements(113,117,1); I think it has something to do with this line of the task: The parameter startIndex can be greater than the length of the array. Implement a continuous addressing by looping through the array from the beginning again. The parameter everyIth can also be greater than the length of the array. However, at least one element, namely the 0-th element of the sub-array, should always be deleted

Comment: Yep added a fix.  Please try to learn from it and improve it yourself.

Comment: I have modified the code to take into account (5, 7, 13)